# how to override and bind to projected content attributes

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

assume that their is 2 components. parent component  `page` and child component `field`. i want to pass an `input` html tag/element from the `page` to the `field` using content projection. then inside the `field` component i want to modify the passed `input` html element attributes. for example setting the field max/min length to a hardcoded length and bind (blur) event to a function.

code samples.

> in page.component:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: `
  <field>
    <input type="text">
  </field>`
})
export class PageComponent  {}
```

> in field component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  template: `
  <ng-content  select="input"></ng-content>
  `
})
export class FieldComponent  {
  length = 14;
  onBlur()
  {
    console.log('blured');
  }
}
```

I tried to do something like this (obviously that didn't work) but hopefully it will make my point more clear

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  template: `
  <ng-content maxLength="length" minLength="length" (blur) ="onBlur()" select="input"></ng-content>
  `
})
export class FieldComponent  {
  length = 14;
  onBlur()
  {
    console.log('blured');
  }
}
```

note: i couldn't find a way/technique/pattern on how to do this. searching words like the title above only directs me to articles that teach how to use content projection or advanced use cases and this one isn't part of them. maybe i couldn't find the correct term to search it. if that so please tell me what is this process named. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please improve your question, it is tough to understand. If you write a better, more complete easy to understand the issue, you enhance the possibility of somebody answering it.